# How to type in backtick and tilde in Safar in macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari

Is there any way to type in a backtick and tilde, the key located on the top-left of the keyboard (below the esc key) in Safari in macOS?

For some reasons this key works in all the other applications but don't in Safari. Also, I think this worked before Safari 9 or 8; I don't know why Apple ditched it, but I still want to know any ways to type in the key.

---

#### UPDATE

I just found that this key works when you type in the search bar on the top of the status bar. However, the key doesn't work if you type in other situations, such as typing in the text field within any pages, including a google search and that in Stack Exchange. In fact while I'm writing this right now in Safari, I cannot type in the backtick and tilde character...

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using? I just tested in Safari 9 and it works fine. I strongly doubt Apple removed the ability to type those characters from Safari.

Comment: @tubedogg Just updated; Can you type in the text field of a page in this site, such as composing a new question?

Comment: Here is back tick ` and here is tilda ~. Typed from MacBook Pro keyboard in Safari. Works fine in any other text field. I am on Sierra macOS.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it work in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: @Allan Yes, that's why I wonder...

Comment: It's most likely a bug in Safari in Sierra.  You've confirmed that its not an application issue nor a web site issue, the only place it's failing is in Safari.  Best bet is to submit a bug report:  http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to 'System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard' and check option 'Show viewers for keyboard, emoji, and symbols in menu bar' (see picture).
Then click on flag in the menu bar and select 'Show keyboard viewer'. Keyboard with your current layout shall appear. Check that you have there 'back tick' and 'tilda' symbols. Try to print them in the text field pressing buttons of this on-screen keyboard with your mouse.

[image]
[image]